# coin::wilcox_test versus wilcox.test in R

Tags: r

In trying to figure out which one is better to use I have come across two issues.

1) The W statistic given by wilcox.test is different from that of coin::wilcox_test. Here's my output:

wilcox_test:

```
Exact Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney Rank Sum Test

data:  data$variableX by data$group (yes, no) 
Z = -0.7636, p-value = 0.4489
alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
```

wilcox.test:

```
Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  data$variable by data$group
W = 677.5, p-value = 0.448
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

I'm aware that there's actually two values for W and that the smaller one is usually reported. When wilcox.test is used with comma instead of "~" I can get the other value, but this comes up as W = 834.5. From what I understand, coin::statistic() can return three different statistics using ("linear", "standarized", and "test") where "linear" is the normal W and "standardized" is just the W converted to a z-score. None of these match up to the W I get from wilcox.test though (linear = 1055.5, standardized = 0.7636288, test = -0.7636288). Any ideas what's going on?

2) I like the options in wilcox_test for "distribution" and "ties.method", but it seems that you can not apply a continuity correction like in wilcox.test. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue when trying to apply [Wendt](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/resolve/doi?DOI=10.1002/ejsp.2420020412) formula to compute effect sizes using the `coin` package, and obtained aberrant *r* values due to the fact that the linear statistic outputted by `wilcox_test()` is unadjusted.

A great explanation is already given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/79849/14197), and therefore I will simply address how to obtain adjusted U statistics with the `wilcox_test()` function. Let's use a the following data frame:

```
d <- data.frame( x = c(rnorm(n = 60, mean = 10, sd = 5), rnorm(n = 30, mean = 16, sd = 5)), 
                 g = c(rep("a",times = 60), rep("b",times = 30)) )
```

We can perform identical tests with `wilcox.test()` and `wilcox_test()`:

```
 w1 <- wilcox.test( formula = x ~ g, data = d ) 
 w2 <- wilcox_test( formula = x ~ g, data = d )
```

Which will output two distinct statistics:

```
> w1$statistic
   W 
 321 

> w2@statistic@linearstatistic
[1] 2151
```

The values are indeed totally different (albeit the tests are equivalent).

To obtain the U statistics identical to that of `wilcox.test()`, you need to subtract `wilcox_test()`'s output statistic by the minimal value that the sum of the ranks of the **reference sample** can take, which is `n_1(n_1+1)/2`.

Both commands take the first level in the factor of your grouping variable `g` as reference (which will by default be alphabetically ordered).

Then you can compute the smallest sum of the ranks possible for the reference sample:

```
n1  <- table(w2@statistic@x)[1]
```

And

```
w2@statistic@linearstatistic-  n1*(n1+1)/2 == w1$statistic
```

should return `TRUE`

Voilà.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be one is performing Mann-Whitney's U and the other Wilcoxon rank test, which is defined in many different ways in literature. They are pretty much equivalent, just look at the p-value. If you want continuity correction in wilcox.test just use argument `correct=T`.

Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79843/is-the-w-statistic-outputted-by-wilcox-test-in-r-the-same-as-the-u-statistic

Comment: @ José Typing ?wilcox_test and ?wilcox.test show some info but both packages tell the reader to refer to Hollander & Wolfe (1973) and Bauer (1972) as the basis of their calculations. So I'm not sure if it is as simple as that. Also, I know that correct=T applies a continuity correction in wilcox.test, but what I wanted to know was whether I can apply a continuity correction in wilcox_test as well.

Comment: any thoughts on my comment?