# Wilcoxon test in R in the presence of ex-aequo when the sample size is low

Tags: r

Why is there a warning message with wilcox.test() but not with wilcox_test() in the presence of ex-aequo when the sample size is low?

```
library("rstatix")
grp1<-c(2,3,4,4,5,5,6)
grp2<-c(1,2,2,2,3,3,5)
base<-data.frame(grp=c(rep("A",7),rep("B",7)),x=c(grp1,grp2))
wilcox.test(grp1,grp2)
wilcox_test(base,x~grp)
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but you can please clarify what "in the presence of ex-aequo" means?

Comment: I guess it means "ties" ?

Answer (score 1):

This issue likely arises due to ties. `rstatix::wilcox_test` is simply suppressing the warnings about ties, as you can see [in their Github repository](https://github.com/kassambara/rstatix/blob/8044e6c4085ac893b2b5d09eb3a0838c13657785/R/utilities_two_sample_test.R#L102-L107). If you want to specify what to do with ties, you may want to look into `coin::wilcox_test` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450221/coinwilcox-test-versus-wilcox-test-in-r))

Comment: ok, thanks for your complete answer, and for `coin::wilcox_test`.